# Order by is not working?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem with order by articles by priority. Where is working. Any suggestion?

```
 $articles =  Articles::whereHas('priority',function($query){
          $query->orderBy('order','asc');
          // $query->where('order','=',1);
        })->limit(7)->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `join` to fetch the `articles` by the order of related table column as:

```
Articles::join('priority', 'articles.id', '=', 'priorities.article_id')
        ->orderBy('priorities.order','asc')
        ->select('articles.*')
        ->limit(7)
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
$quotes=Articles::orderBy('priority', 'desc')->limit(7)->get();
```

Comment: i dont have priority in articles its in another table

Comment: I have tables articles and table homepage_priorties. In homepage_priorites i have article_id and order

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$articles = Articles::orderBy('order','desc')->limit(7)->get();
```

and if you want to add a condition you can use somthing like this:

```
$articles = Articles::join('priorities','articles.id','=','priorities.articale_id')->where('priority',1)->orderBy('order','desc')->limit(7)->get();
```